# Problems with deploying nuxt.js with express and mongodb on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, nuxt.js

So I have problem with deploying my app on heroku. I've made app using nuxt with express.js on backend. It is using mongod as database. Everything works fine on loalhost but when I followed this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@ale_colombo/deploy-nuxt-js-app-on-heroku-531a935bce90

My app won't work in production. On main page shows server error. I don't have idea what is wrong. I am deploying nuxt.js app first time.

Logs heroku shows:

```
2020-06-15T07:11:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-15T07:11:18.902707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-15T07:11:24.260338+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:24.260358+00:00 app[web.1]: > pai@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-15T07:11:24.260359+00:00 app[web.1]: > cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js
2020-06-15T07:11:24.260360+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:25.624765+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:25.624795+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN  No .env file found in /app.
2020-06-15T07:11:25.624796+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:25.721532+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:25.721536+00:00 app[web.1]: READY  Server listening on http://urlhere
2020-06-15T07:11:25.721537+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:25.838724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-15T07:11:44.168573+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:44.168585+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
2020-06-15T07:11:44.168585+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:44.168589+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
2020-06-15T07:11:44.168590+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-15T07:11:44.178096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-fortress-45777.herokuapp.com request_id=e6186311-46a7-471c-854f-fc42dd8e5266 fwd="***" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=92ms status=500 bytes=1228 protocol=https
```

There is connect Error but i don't know how to fix it. I couldn't find any solution for that. At first I have got Procfile but i've read somewhere that it is not required but after removing it app won't work too.

That's my server/index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const consola = require("consola");
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require("nuxt");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require("../nuxt.config.js");
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

  await nuxt.ready();
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use("/api", require("./router"));
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host);
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  });
}
start();
```

Comment: you sure your `.env` file is there? because he cant find it

Comment: Yeah i see that too but i have .env in my root folder. I'm not sure if nuxt build added one. Should i create .env in production files? Inside .nuxt/dist ?

Comment: what mode do you use? spa, universal, static?

Comment: universal. ssr.

Comment: I tested minute ago and server/api works fine. It wont serve pages idk why. So sorry for stupid answers from me but really I'm making this first time and i don;t understand everything perfectly :)

Comment: you have a dist folder in SSR mode?

Comment: I'am making this really first time so maybe I'll tell what i have because i don't know what I'm doing. I have my nuxt project. I initialized git then ran yarn build then ran heroku create then I added, commited and pushed all to github. And that's my app: https://safe-fortress-45777.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I'm using express as backend framework in ssr nuxt app

Comment: and yeah i have dist in .nuxt/dist

Comment: but idk what is that

Comment: i have done it like this: i have grabbed my whole projekt and uploaded it on the server. and there i have run `npm run build` and then `npm run start`

Comment: ok so how i can do that using heroku? Push all to github and then where run npm run start?

Comment: did you tried this out? https://nuxtjs.org/faq/heroku-deployment/

Comment: https://vueschool.io/lessons/how-to-deploy-nuxtjs-to-heroku?friend=nuxt

Comment: Yeah guy in this medium article refers to this docs but that's good idea to try again only with docs

Comment: Yeah. I made all the same but i run yarn build also. Do you think that running yarn build before pushing to github causes this problem?

Comment: well i dont know

Comment: ok thanks now my whole app dont want to work ;D. I think that i have to try something easier first. Thanks for help!

Comment: In your error its says its failing: to connect here: `127.0.0.1:3000` but in the medium article it says to set your host to `$ heroku config:set HOST=0.0.0.0`. Maybe something to look at?